# show() function doesnt work in div

Tags: jquery, html

I am showing and hiding a div which contains loading/waiting gif image. 
on click of a button i call `$("#div").show()` and `.hide()` at the end of click function. but image is not showing generally. When I put break point next to `.show()` line it shows the image.

I also tried `.css("display","")`, but it wont worked.

Please suggest any other way, or tell me what could be the problem.

Thanks.

my code looks like, below

```
$("#button").click(function(){

   $("#div").show(); // showing image so that user will know that a process is going on.

   //other working code

   $("#div").hide();   // hiding will indicate process completion
});
```

Comment: is the id of the image really 'div'?

Comment: If the code runs very fast the image won't appear before its removed. You should put in a setTimeout call to hide the image.

Comment: If you put `.show()` and `.hide()` in the same function block, it will immediately hide the `$("#div")` you're trying to show. You may want to hide that only when the other process is completed. Depending on what your other codes are, something like a `.done()` function may help.

Comment: I can bet your *other working code* is an AJAX call, which is asynchronous, and so allows the hide code to run even before it is finished. Instead, do the `$("#div").hide();` once the AJAX call is finished, using its callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded and the same thread is shared for UI rendering and script execution. Because of the way the browsers does optimization you are not seeing the show() and hide() effects.

You could make use of JQuery promise mechanism to solve your problem.
Examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Instead of doing this way

> 1) show the DIV
>
> 2) execute some code
>
> 3) hide the DIV

you will de doing this

> 1) show the div
>
> 2) When 'show' is complete
>
> ```
>            2.1) execute your code, 
>            2.2) hide the DIV
> ```

I created a JSbin working example [here](http://jsbin.com/umecip/14/edit)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling show and hide with no animation in the same function call. Because this is happening synchronously the 2 function calls will be made in the same thread because JavaScript is single threaded. You will not notice any change at all because it shows and hides on the same thread before the browser can even update the display. If there were some sort of asynchronous call you would see it, but you don't appear to have any.

You can fake it by putting all your working code after the initial show inside a setTimeout.

```
$("#div").show();
setTimeout(function(){
    ...other working code
    $("#div").hide();
}, 100);
```

This will delay the processing by 100ms, but once the processing starts, if the working code part takes a second to complete your animated gif won't actually animate because the display of the animation can't run while JavaScript is executing (due to the browser's single threaded behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Browser has a very **fancy** working style that, when a **script is executing**, it **delays all interface drawing** after the script is done.

So in your code, the browser does show the div (you could get the right `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`) but you cannot see it (because the drawing is delayed).

The debugger creates a break point on code and right there browser flushes all changes to your screen so you can see the image, an `alert()` call can result to the same effect.

My above state is not 100% correct, since actually browser is working under a **event loop** and delays all the **layout** and **drawing** and more other works when script is executing, but I think it could answer your question, if you want a more precise and complex answer, I would be glad to write more :)

Comment: In my case, there is only javascript code (like if..else, loops, dom traversing and manupulation, and no ajax or any kind of asynch thing) between.show() and .hide(). Yes, but in between these two some very complex code is there, complex in terms of inner loops and function calls. I think the problem is due to javascript hangs the browser and DOM/element property changes does not happens.